# Convert JSR-303 validation errors to Spring's BindingResult

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I have the following code in a Spring controller:

```java
@Autowired
private javax.validation.Validator validator;

@RequestMapping(value = "/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitForm(CustomForm form) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<CustomForm>> errors = validator.validate(form);
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to map `errors` to Spring's `BindingResult` object without manually going through all the errors and adding them to the `BindingResult`? Something like this:

```
// NOTE: this is imaginary code
BindingResult bindingResult = BindingResult.fromConstraintViolations(errors);
```

I know it is possible to annotate the `CustomForm` parameter with `@Valid` and let Spring inject `BindingResult` as another method's parameter, but it's not an option in my case.

```
// I know this is possible, but doesn't work for me
public String submitForm(@Valid CustomForm form, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A simpler approach could be to use Spring's abstraction `org.springframework.validation.Validator` instead, you can get hold of a validator by having this bean in the context:

```
<bean id="jsr303Validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />

@Autowired @Qualifier("jsr303Validator") Validator validator;
```

With this abstraction in place, you can use the validator this way, passing in your bindingResult:

```
validator.validate(obj, bindingResult);
```

Comment: Thanks! That's definitely more concise.

Comment: I don't see method validate which accepts BindingResult

Comment: If you don't see the validate method that accepts the binding results, it means your Validator validator is a javax.validation.Validator. Change it to a org.springframework.validation.Validator and you'll be fine. No need to change the bean definition.

Answer (score 5):

Spring uses a SpringValidatorAdapter to convert javax.validation.ConstraintViolation objects to ObjectError or FieldError objects, as found in the binding result.
The BindStatus then uses a message source (like the web application context itself) to translate the errors.
In short, you could do:

```
SpringValidatorAdapter springValidator = new SpringValidatorAdapter(validator);
BindingResult bindingResult= new BeanPropertyBindingResult(myBeanToValidate, "myBeanName");
springValidator.validate(myBeanToValidate, bindingResult);
```

This is easier when writing a unit test, because you don't even need to create a Spring context.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Kristiaan's answer,  for testing purposes it is not necessary to create a spring context to validate using Spring's bindingResult.  The following is an example:

```
public class ValidatorTest {

    javax.validation.Validator javaxValidator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
    org.springframework.validation.Validator springValidator = new SpringValidatorAdapter(javaxValidator);

    @Test
    public void anExampleTest() {

    JSR303AnnotatedClassToTest   ctt  = new JSR303AnnotatedClassToTest( ..init vars..)

    ... test setup...

    WebDataBinder dataBinder = new WebDataBinder(ctt);
    dataBinder.setValidator(springValidator);
    dataBinder.validate();
    BindingResult bindingResult = dataBinder.getBindingResult(); 

    ... test analysis ...

    }
}
```

This approach doesn't require creating a binding result ahead of time,  the dataBinder builds the right one for you.

Answer (score 1):

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitForm(CustomForm form) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<CustomForm>> errors = validator.validate(form);

    BindingResult bindingResult = toBindingResult(errors, form, "form");
    ...
}

private BindingResult toBindingResult(ConstraintViolationException e, Object object, String objectName) {
    BindingResult bindingResult = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(object, objectName);
    new AddConstraintViolationsToErrors().addConstraintViolations(e.getConstraintViolations(), bindingResult);
    return bindingResult;
}

private static class AddConstraintViolationsToErrors extends SpringValidatorAdapter {
    public AddConstraintViolationsToErrors() {
        super(Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator()); // Validator is not actually used
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
    public void addConstraintViolations(Set<? super ConstraintViolation<?>> violations, Errors errors) {
        // Using raw type since processConstraintViolations specifically expects ConstraintViolation<Object>
        super.processConstraintViolations((Set) violations, errors);
    }
}
```

Unlike the other answers to this question, this solution handles the case where there already exists a `Set<ConstraintViolation<?>>` which needs to be converted to to a `BindingResult`.

### Explanation

Spring provides the [`SpringValidatorAdapter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/SpringValidatorAdapter.html) class to perform bean validations, storing the results in an [`Errors`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html) instance (note that `BindingResult` extends `Errors`).  The normal manual use of this class would be to use it to perform the validations via the [`validate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/SpringValidatorAdapter.html#validate-java.lang.Object-org.springframework.validation.Errors-) method:

```java
Validator beanValidator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
SpringValidatorAdapter validatorAdapter = new SpringValidatorAdapter(beanValidator);

BindException bindException = new BindException(form, "form");
validatorAdapter.validate(form, bindException);
```

However, this doesn't help in the case where there already exists a `Set<ConstraintViolation<?>>` which needs to be converted to a `BindingResult`.

It is still possible to achieve this goal, though it does require jumping through a couple extra hoops.  `SpringValidatorAdapter` contains a [`processConstraintViolations`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/SpringValidatorAdapter.html#processConstraintViolations-java.util.Set-org.springframework.validation.Errors-) method which converts the `ConstraintViolation` objects into the appropriate Spring [`ObjectError`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/ObjectError.html) subtypes, and stores them on an `Errors` object.  However, this method is protected, limiting its accesibility to subclasses.

This limitation can be worked around by creating a custom subclass of `SpringValidatorAdapter` which delegates to or exposes the protected method.  It is not a typical usage, but it works.

```java
public class AddConstraintViolationsToErrors extends SpringValidatorAdapter {
    public AddConstraintViolationsToErrors() {
        super(Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator()); // Validator is not actually used
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
    public void addConstraintViolations(Set<? super ConstraintViolation<?>> violations, Errors errors) {
        // Using raw type since processConstraintViolations specifically expects ConstraintViolation<Object>
        super.processConstraintViolations((Set) violations, errors);
    }
}
```

This custom class can be used to populate a newly created `BindingResult`, achieving the goal of creating a `BindingResult` from a `Set<ConstraintViolation<?>>`.

```java
private BindingResult toBindException(ConstraintViolationException e, Object object, String objectName) {
    BindingResult bindingResult = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(object, objectName);
    new AddConstraintViolationsToErrors().addConstraintViolations(e.getConstraintViolations(), bindingResult);
    return bindingResult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar issue and this is how I resolved it.

Given your example, this is how I implemented it

First, I used a smart validator, and in the method I let spring inject the BindingResult

```
@Autowired
private org.springframework.validation.SmartValidator validator;

@RequestMapping(value = "/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitForm(CustomForm form, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<CustomForm>> errors = validator.validate(form);
    ...
}
```

And then using that binding result i pass it in the SmartValidator so that any errors will be bounded to BindingResult.

```
validator.validate(form, bindingResult);
if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
     throw new BindException(bindingResult);
}
```